# substr function displaying incorrectly

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using substr() function something like this:

```
<a href="#">link</a>
<?php echo substr($item->introtext,0,75);?>
<a href="#">read-more</a>
```

When the introtext has more than 75 characters it's displaying incorrectly like this:

```
<a href="#">link</a>
<p>introtext paragraphs here<a href="#">read-more</a></p>
```

But when the introtext has less than 75 characters it's displaying correctly like this:

```
<a href="#">link</a>
<p>introtext paragraphs here</p>
<a href="#">read-more</a>
```

Please note that read-more is inside p when introtext has more than 75 character but not when less than 75 characters.

My entire code is here:

```
<ul class="latestnews<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
<h3>news</h3>
<?php foreach ($list as $item) :  ?>

    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$item->id; /* echo $item->link;*/ ?>">
            <?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
          <?php echo substr($item->introtext,0,75);?>
          <br /><a class="learn-more" href="<?php echo 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$item->id; //* echo $item->link;*/ ?>">learn more</a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: How is the `paragraph` tag getting added there?

Comment: please show the entire php.

Comment: I'm using joomla and introtext is taken from article and in which the paragraph tag is comming.

Comment: The 2nd o/p is supposed to be correct but you say it's wrong. `<a href="#">read-more</a>` is already outside the text that will come from the php block with substr. Anyhow the anchor text is already outside. So the 1st one that you say is correct is wrong I think. Pls review.

Comment: @RajeshPaul Thanks. I reviewed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reason

When `$item->introtext` has **less than 75 characters** then the closing tag `</p>` is certainly within the 75 characters and hence the structure will be-

```
<p>paragraph content</p>
<a href="#">read-more</a>
```

But when `$item->introtext` has **more than 75 characters** then the closing tag `</p>` is definitely not there in the string returned by `substr()`-function. Hence the resultant is as follows-

```
<p>paragraph content<a href="#">read-more</a>
//As closing tag </p> is not there hence the link "read-more" is considered inside the <p>..</p> scope.
```

### Solution

`<?php echo substr($item->introtext,0,75);?>` is causing the problem.

So you can do one thing i.e. strip all the tags in the text so that the `substr()` doesn't count the **tags** and **style statements** and apply all necessary styles thereafter. So change your code as-

```
<?php echo substr(strip_tags($item->introtext),0,75);?>
```

Comment: `<p><span>introtext</span></p>` should display introtext. Shouldn't be a problem. What do you mean **`75 characters text from whole html`**?

Comment: So basically you just need the text but not the enclosing tags, isn't it? please confirm and let me edit my ans.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43806/discussion-between-rajesh-paul-and-c-link)

Comment: There's one blank html `<p></p>` appearing

Comment: Did you notice for blank html?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it appears that the `<p>` tags are actually in the introtext.

So to work around this problem you need to trim the closing tags from the end of the strings.

```
<ul class="latestnews<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
<h3>news</h3>
<?php foreach ($list as $item) :  ?>

    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$item->id; /* echo $item->link;*/ ?>">
            <?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
          <?php echo substr(rtrim($item->introtext,"</p>"),0,75);?>
          <br /><a class="learn-more" href="<?php echo 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$item->id; //* echo $item->link;*/ ?>">learn more</a>
          </p>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

The above code will remove the closing `</p>` tag and create another one after the end of the learn more link.

Good luck

Comment: Check his updated question. Your answer will be wrong as per the question after the edit.

Comment: @micb Your code also worked fine for me. But problem I faced is that if introtext has <p><span>introtext</span></p> then it is not display. What can I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla has built-in functions for smart trimming of things like intro text: JHtmlString::truncate(), JHtmlString::truncateComplex(),  JHtmlString::abridge().  I'd use truncateComplex because you probably want 75 characters to render but not counting the html as characters.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer related to my question on JHtmlString::truncateComplex() as I ain't able to find proper documentation about that

Comment: Read the code and then read the tests which show how inputs and ouputs work. Basically what happens is that the simple truncate will either give you 75 characters of straight text, stripping all html or it will give you 75 characters including html characters, with tidied up html.  TruncateComplex will give you 75 characters of text plus any html that enclosed that text (that is the html tags are not counted against your number of characters) and it will make sure that all open tags are closed. So <p> will always have </p> for example.